# Fun with tags hierarchy

Tags: discussion, tags

Since we already have 7 pages of tags, and some tags are supersets or subsets of the other, I think it would be neat if we have some kind of page or wiki where we can see the relationships among all these tags, in other words, their hierarchy.

So here I am suggesting that we all get together and organize all the tags we have into hierarchy. Feel free to modify the community wiki below.

This is just for fun. You don't have to participate if you don't want to ;)

Answer (score 1):

- [vocabulary](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary)

  - [etymology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)
  - [word-choices](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choices)
  - [loanwords](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loanwords)

    - [wasei-eigo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wasei-eigo)
  - [synonyms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms)
  - [set-phrases](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-phrases)

    - [idioms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms)
- [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)

  - [syntax](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)

    - [conjugations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugations)
    - [negative-forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-forms)
    - [questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions)
  - [particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles)

    - [particle-ni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni)
    - [particle-to](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-to)
    - [particle-de](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-de)
    - [particle-na](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-na)
    - [particle-wo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-wo)
- [writing](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing)

  - [kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji)

    - [homophonic-kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophonic-kanji)
    - [ateji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ateji)
  - [kana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kana)

    - [hiragana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiragana)
    - [katakana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/katakana)
    - [okurigana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okurigana)
    - [furigana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/furigana)
  - [spelling](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling)
- [usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)

  - [gender](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender)
  - [practical](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practical)

    - [business-japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-japanese)
- [speaking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking)

  - [pronunciation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation)
  - [colloquial](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colloquial)

    - [dialects](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects)

      - [kansai-ben](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kansai-ben)
    - [slang](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slang)
  - [readings](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readings)
- [culture](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture)

  - [keigo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keigo)

    - [honorifics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honorifics)
- [linguistics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics)

  - [terminology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
  - [history](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)

    - [language-reform](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-reform)
    - [language-change](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change)

Comment: Where would the terminology stuff fall under?

Comment: @Troyen I'm putting it under linguistics

Comment: i'd put keigo and honorifics under usage with business japanese or under grammar since it is a specific grammar point that is taught in elementary japanese classes.

Also i wouldn't put dialects under colliquial as there are keigo variations even among the dialects.

I also thing it is weird ot put readings under speaking.  Maybe under kanji makes more sense

Comment: @Mark Feel free to edit. I don't mind :) Also, I think it's okay to put one tag under more than one parent ..

Comment: Yeah, I do not think that it is possible to put tags strictly in a tree, and it makes more sense to allow multiple parents.  A problem with that is that there is no easy way to draw a tree like that in a post (technically, it is not a tree but a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)).